# Retrieve object from vector based on its type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function to retrieve an object:

```
template <class T>
class SystemManager {
public:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseSystem<T>>> container_;

  template <template <typename> class S> // S<T> inherits from BaseSystem<T>
  std::shared_ptr<S<T>> retrieve() {
    return object of type S<T> from container_;
  }
};
```

Is there a way to retrieve the object based on its type like this? Is there maybe a way to do it with `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: Can you guarantee that you only have one instance of each type that derives `BaseSystem` in the container?

Comment: @CollinDauphinee Yes, and it should overwrite existing instances on insert/add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to iterate through the `vector` and try [`dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) on each element, return the first one that succeeds.

Another solution, if you can change the container, would be to use a `map`, or an `unordered_map`, with [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) as the key, and the `shared_ptr` as value.

Answer (score 0):

a basic solution would be

```
#define STRING 1
#define INT    2
...
vector<pair<x,y>> container;

if(container[i].first == STRING)
// do something
```

where first element of pair is the type as int. Before you add element to your vector (assuming) you already know what type it is store it as a pair .

```
container.push_back(make_pair(TYPE, myrealdata);
```

Another solution would be

```
vector<MyClass> container

class MyClass
{
    int type = STRING;
}
```

where other classes inherit MyClass and check that value for type.